# Finding out how many Wordpress plugins exist

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to find out how many Wordpress plugins there are. Not downloaded and installed, just available on the official Wordpress site!

```
$plugins = plugins_api('query_plugins');
echo $plugins->info['results'];
```

This returns: **54527**

Why do I get this value?

The official [Wordpress site](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/) tells me that they are **56171** plugins (for now).

Is there something wrong with my code? If not, which number is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of reasons you could get different plugin counts depending on how you query:  caching, deleted plugins that still appear in the directory, differences between published plugin pages and plugins available for download, and probably more.

All of the code involved is open source if you want to look into this further, but IMO it's probably not worth spending too much time on.

The official WordPress site that says 56,171 plugins is using [this code](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/browser/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/pub/wporg-plugins/header.php?rev=7634&marks=34,38#L23) to count.

The plugins API that says 54,527 plugins is using [this code](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/browser/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/api/routes/class-query-plugins.php?rev=7634&marks=52,66,69,73#L34) to count.

So far those two methods look pretty much the same.  However, the plugins API has [aggressive caching applied](https://meta.trac.wordpress.org/browser/sites/trunk/wordpress.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/standalone/class-plugins-info-api.php?rev=7634&marks=4#L1).

If you want to get an exact count of all plugins that can actually be downloaded, you'll probably have to download them yourself.  See:  https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Plugin-Directory-Slurper

It wouldn't surprise me too much if this method yielded a third, different number.